# How to have different colors for the same border?

Tags: html, css, gradient

[image: Colored Border]

^ This is what the output should be.

It is about the border-bottom attribute of a div, which takes full width of the viewport.

I have searched SO, and I have tried answers, but the problem is, some of them adddress borders in all directions, and others have different colored borders, not in the same line.

How can this be achieved with Pure CSS, or any of its preproessors?

Also, I can place the image and make it responsive using [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com), but that beats the purpose. So, Answers like use it as an image are useless.

> Mind the spacing.

Comment: Thanks, -1. Cant solve. Let's downvote.

Comment: With a single HTML element I doubt this is possible at all, but I've seen so many impressive things done only with clever CSS recently that I couldn't be 100% affirmative. Edit : answer from Akshay just proved my point although there's no spacing in it.

Comment: Exactly,that is why I posted this question mentioning `a div`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple box shadows to achieve this

i created an `:after` pseudo element and used `box-shadow`s to duplicate it with different colors. You add more colors by adding 100 to the previous `box-shadow`

```css
div{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    background:lightgrey;
}

div:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:100px;
    height:3px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    bottom:0;
    box-shadow:105px 0 0 0 red,210px 0 0 0 yellow,315px 0 0 0 green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to set white spaces between colors, just do little calculation and add in parameter box-shadow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
        width:520px;
        height:100px;
        position:relative;
        background:lightgrey;
    }

    div:after{
        position:absolute;
        content:"";
        width:100px;
        height:3px;
        background:dodgerblue;
        bottom:0;
        box-shadow:5px 0 0 0 white,105px 0 0 0 red,110px 0 0 0 white,210px 0 0 0 yellow,215px 0 0 0 white,315px 0 0 0 green,320px 0 0 0 white,420px 0 0 0 orange;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, at first I just want to comment post from Akshay, but it didn't give me spaces to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this with border property then you should follow the following steps:

1. create a image looking like this:

[image: Image name:border.jpg]

2. use following CSS and HTML

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style> 
   div{
   margin: 0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:100%;
   height:100px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   border-bottom: 4px solid;
   -webkit-border-image: url(border.jpg) 0  0 10 0 stretch; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
   -o-border-image: url(border.jpg)0 0 10 0 stretch; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
   border-image: url(border.jpg)0 0 10 0 stretch;
   }

   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```